Is the Star Trek TNG episode Aquiel inspired by The Thing?
I just rewatched the Star Trek: The Next Generation episode Aquiel (season 6, Ep. 13) and there are some very obvious plot similarities with The Thing (1982):

both happen on a distant isolated outpost
both feature a shape shifting alien that can perfectly mimic other life forms
characters in both stories get paranoid about who to trust due to the alien's ability to impersonate individuals
both plots revolve around characters investigating mysterious past events
in both the alien takes over the dog...

It's not exactly the same but is there any evidence that the writers used The Thing (or the 1938 novella it's adapted from, Who Goes There?) as inspiration for this episode?

This has become a trope in SF. Shapeshifting murderers almost always induce paranoia since you never know if your friend is really them.

The writers talk about the convoluted process by which this episode came about. Initially it was just going to be a straightforward murder mystery where La Forge would fall in love with a dead woman by reading her video log entries while investigating her apparent murder. The twist would be that she was not actually dead, allowing La Forge to build a more lasting (and recurring) relationship with her.

This story, generally felt to be one of the few disappointments of the
season, originally began as yet another try at providing Geordi a
recurring romance while tying into Piller’s suggestion of a mystery in
the manner of the classic movie Laura—falling in love with someone who
first appears to be dead and then turns up alive.
Star Trek: The Next Generation Companion

Apparently the first draft script was felt to be too much like Basic Instinct and various other potential murderers were considered before the writers eventually settled on the dog(!).

Moore said the problem was that no one was ever satisfied with the
person “whodunit.” Aquiel was initially to have been the killer, but
when the plot seemed to be veering toward a Basic Instinct clone, both
the Klingon and the dead Keith Rocha—named by Moore for another one of
his high-school friends—were in turn considered for the murderer and
then dropped as seeming too obvious. “At one point,” he recalled, “we
finally said ‘Why not the dog?’ He had always been in the script; we
had meant to leave him with Geordi from that time on.”

The meandering way in which the final antagonist was chosen puts the mockers on the idea that the setting was chosen to be like The Thing, given that the outpost, the murder, the paranoid accusations, etc., were all in place before the writers decided that it was the dog whodidit.
